# Travelling from USA to India With Controlled Medications

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, india, health, drugs

Are you allowed to travel with a valid 30 day prescription for controlled medications from USA to India? Or are they prohibited?

Comment: You could try emailing the Indian Consulate closest to where you live https://www.indianembassyusa.gov.in/pages/MTc,

Answer (score 1):

Assume they are prohibited unless you find proof that this medicine is allowed under those conditions. And only take official sources, as people on internet can tell you anything.

For some medicines you only need a prescription, others may not be imported at all, and some medicines are free to buy in other countries but absolutely forbidden in other countries.

Also check availability and price in India, as medicines are not cheap in the USA. It might work to travel with a small supply and buy more at your destination.

You might get a more precise answer if you share which medicines you need to travel with.